# How to display all records from the table ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I have db with this table (TableToDo):

http://goo.gl/NlTEk

I want display all records in TableToDo where `login==Joe`.

All records I display so:
Controller:

```
ASPNETDBEntities __db = new ASPNETDBEntities();
public ActionResult Index(TableToDo obj)
{
    var th = (from TableToDo in __db.TableToDo select TableToDo).ToList();

    return View(th);
}
```

and strongly-typed View(List):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.text)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("x", "Delete", new { id = item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Please tell me how display all records in TableToDo where login==Joe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do that when you get the data from the data source. So update your query to

```
 var th = (from TableToDo in __db.TableToDo where TableToDo.Login="Joe" select TableToDo).ToList();
```

Comment: thx.
What I may do, if I want display all records of curren registred user?

Comment: @user: Get the current registered user name and keep in a variable and replace that with "Joe"

Comment: @user: Where are u geting the registered user from ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var th = (
            from TableToDo in __db.TableToDo 
            where TableToDo.Login=="Joe" 
            select TableToDo
         ).ToList();
```

**Edit**

Or do you want to use the input of the function. Then maybe something like this:

```
var th = (
            from TableToDo in __db.TableToDo 
            where TableToDo.id==obj.id
            select TableToDo
         ).ToList();
```

Or if you want to mach the object with the name the something like this:

```
var th = (
            from TableToDo in __db.TableToDo 
            where TableToDo.Login==obj.Login
            select TableToDo
         ).ToList();
```

Comment: this is not the solution to my problem

Comment: Ok. So where is the current user coming from?

Answer (score 0):

It very simple :) Let's assume you have a simple POCO class Record:

```
 public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

This class refers to database table Records via db context:

```
 public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }
}
```

Then in controller you just create a new Context object and via it get all records from Record table:

```
Context context = new Context();
List<Record> records = context.Records.ToList();
```